# Does nginx clear files in cache directory

Tags: nginx

I have a few servers running nginx as a cache for larger static files.

Due to changes in disk space needed and so on, I've changed the size of the cache and also split it to multiple locations.

One question I do have though, will nginx clear any files in the cache directory if they are not used within the "inactive" time frame?

I basically want to know if I've made changes that will cause files in the cache location to not be updated by any requests, do I have to delete them myself to reclaim that space, or will nginx consider all files under any cache directory as candidates for eviction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx documentation at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache states

> Cached data that are not accessed during the time specified by the inactive parameter get removed from the cache regardless of their freshness. By default, inactive is set to 10 minutes.

And

> The special “cache manager” process monitors the maximum cache size set by the max_size parameter. When this size is exceeded, it removes the least recently used data. The data is removed in iterations configured by manager_files, manager_threshold, and manager_sleep parameters (1.11.5). During one iteration no more than manager_files items are deleted (by default, 100). The duration of one iteration is limited by the manager_threshold parameter (by default, 200 milliseconds). Between iterations, a pause configured by the manager_sleep parameter (by default, 50 milliseconds) is made.

Based on this information, nginx controls the disk space used.

If you are defining multiple `proxy_cache_path` entries with different `keys_zone=name:size` entries, each entry has its own declaration and counting of inactive time / maximum size of files.

So, if your `keys_zone` `cache1` and `keys_zone` `cache2` have max size 10 GB each, then your caches can take 20 GB in total.